# From Python to TCL: cannot run `elmer` command OSX

Tags: python, interface, path, tcl, wrapper

I wish to port Python modules and run them in TCL, for that i need to install this tool called `elmer` [website](http://elmer.sourceforge.net/manual.html)

According to the ReadMe:

> Run the setup.py script in the "src" directory, giving it the "build"
>   command:
>
> > cd src
> >     python setup.py build
>
> Once built, a subdirectory named "build" will be created in "src".  To
>   remove the build, simply remove the build directory and all of it's
>   contents.
>
> To install elmer, run setup.py with the "install" command:
>
> > python setup.py install
>
> This will install elmer to the default location, which is the Python
>   "site-packages" directory in the Python library for the elmer sources,
>   and the "Scripts" directory for the elmer script.

I did `python setup.py install --user` and when I type `elmer` it does not run the tool.

My `$PATH` is : `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`

Comment: Where did it get installed? What location does the `--user` option specify?

Comment: @glennjackman `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/site-packages/elmer/`, ive tried adding it to path and to pythonpath to no avail

Comment: How have you tried?

Comment: @glennjackman in my .bash_profile `export PATH=$PATH:/insert/path/here`, same with PYTHONPATH

Comment: Did you `source ~/.bash_profile`?  Inside that directory is there an executable file named `elmer`? Is there a `bin` directory?

Comment: @glennjackman there is no executable, only `elmer.h` and no bin directory